# How to Middle-Click on Touchscreen in Windows 8.1

Tags: windows-8, windows-8.1, mouse, touchscreen, lenovo-laptop

I thought this would be simple, but I've searched previous SuperUser threads and on Google and I cannot find a way to middle-click on a touchscreen in Windows 8.1 (on a Lenovo laptop in my case).  I've checked all the control panel settings.  There are other options, but nothing for middle-click.

I'd like to be able to use the touchscreen to middle-click on some links to have them open in a new tab (just like I have been doing with a mouse for 15+ years...).  Since I'd also like to be able to open other links in the current tab with left-click, changing the link opening options of the browser doesn't solve the issue.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

One possible solution for you is [TouchMe Gesture Studio](https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/store/apps/touchme-gesture-studio/9wzdncrdg0l8). I'm afraid it's not a free solution, although I believe it gives a trial period to make sure it's compatible with your machine. It gives you a lot more options for touch screen actions you can perform, including middle mouse click.

Otherwise, I'm not sure there are a lot of options without building some sort of custom interpretation for a certain gesture. Annoyingly there are very few settings in the way of customisation for touch screens inputs.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion.  It seems TouchMe only works as a Metro app with a Microsoft account... I have deliberately removed & disabled all Metro functionality on the laptop to avoid that particular walled garden.  I wouldn't mind paying for it, but the rest isn't an option for me.

Comment: @MekkiMacAulay You are correct. Most annoyingly though, I'm fairly sure the software itself (A helper program if you will) is a normal Windows desktop program, and the Metro app is just used to build a configuration file for it. I haven't used it in over a year from when my touch tablet died though, so I'm not sure if that's still the case but I'd assume so. Good luck though!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know any nativ way of soing this but maybe AHK (autohotkey) can help you with this, take a look at [this](https://autohotkey.com/board/topic/52737-using-ahk-to-emulate-middle-mouse-button-on-a-touch-screen/).

Comment: Your link points to a hit on Google for a forum whose "answer" was to search for keywords on same forum, which is no longer active and archived.  I appreciate your intention.